# Glide loading two images

Tags: android-glide

I have the following code which uses a URL to load an image into my layout's ImageView with ID `image` with glide:

```
String imageURL = "https://example.com/image.jpg"

Glide.with(mContext)
                        .load(imageURL)
                        .apply(requestOptions)
                        .into(imageTypeViewHolder.image);
```

However, my layout file also has another ImageView called `image2`.  So far, I am achieving this with:

```
String imageURL = "https://example.com/image.jpg"
String image2URL = "https://example.com/image2.jpg"

Glide.with(mContext)
                        .load(imageURL)
                        .apply(requestOptions)
                        .into(imageTypeViewHolder.image);
Glide.with(mContext)
                        .load(image2URL)
                        .apply(requestOptions)
                        .into(imageTypeViewHolder.image2);
```

Is this the correct way to go about it, or can this be simplified into a single Glide.with?